# How to use $callback in Query?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

We need to apply [whereNotExists](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_whereNotExists) but we have no idea how to pass a [Closure](http://php.net/Closure) to the query, is there any example to use this query?

Comment: There's an example in the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#advanced-where-clauses

Comment: a simple google search would have answered your question